# Почему метод Process.Start отрабатывает с ошибками?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, сеть

Не могу понять, почему не отрабатывает метод Process.Start, выпрыгивает системная ошибка при его вызове.

в консоли вызываю пинг

```
comp@comp0:~$ ping -c 5  www.ya.ru
PING ya.ru (87.250.250.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=4.43 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=4.30 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=4.32 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=4.19 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=4.20 ms

--- ya.ru ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.193/4.293/4.439/0.098 ms
```

Всё отрабатывает безупречно.

Делаю в коде:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;


class TrimTram1
{
   static void Main()
   {
      // ---
      string tes = "ping -c 5 www.ya.ru";
      Process.Start(tes);
      // ---
   }
}
```

Вот вывод:

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mono tehn4.exe 
gio: file:///home/comp/Qt_project/TCP_IP/ping%20-c%205%20www.ya.ru: Ошибка при получении информации о файле «/home/comp/Qt_project/TCP_IP/ping -c 5 www.ya.ru»: Нет такого файла или каталога

Unhandled Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00102] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0001b] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName) [0x00006] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at TrimTram1.Main () [0x0006c] in <06daeafc853b4bc4970944168b738ba3>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00102] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0001b] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName) [0x00006] in <2703bbaa0a6e4686b6033c2dddb1a363>:0 
  at TrimTram1.Main () [0x0006c] in <06daeafc853b4bc4970944168b738ba3>:0
```

Суть ошибки совершенно не ясна

---

*Можете хотя бы посоветовать, куда копать и есть ли книги по C# в Linux*

Comment: Эта перегрузка запускает процесс по имени файла. Попробуйте так: `Process.Start("ping","-c 5 www.ya.ru");`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight (Заработало :-) ) можете пожалуйста оформить как ответ. _А также дополнить рекомендациями по работе в линуксе с си-шарпом_

Comment: Написал. По поводу работы с C# в Linux я не могу посоветовать конкретную книгу. Из сайтов в интернете вот это можно посмотреть по особенностям Mono на Linux: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-portability/ В C# многое не привязано к ОС (как и эта ошибка например, в Windows было бы то же самое)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в виндувсе я как то догадался  (открыть документацию) `Process.Start("IExplore.exe", tes); // примерно так, tes ещё поправить`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перегрузка [Process.Start(string)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-1.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_) запускает процесс по имени файла. Чтобы запустить команду с параметрами, нужно использовать другую перегрузку:

```
Process.Start("ping","-c 5 www.ya.ru");
```